# Zend Framework 2 - Doctrine 2 - How to use fixtures

Tags: php, database, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, fixtures

I'm in the need of using fixtures for putting an initial user into my database.

I had a look at this module which is said to be pretty good: https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures

Unfortunately I don't understand how to use it. Alright, I build a class with my fixtures. And then? I'm used to fixtures in the way that when I create my database (`schema-tool:create`) that the data is automatically written into it.

But where is this connection? It seems that you have to call the Loader at some point in the code?

Would be great if someone could give me a short tutorial how to utilize these (or any other working) fixture module!

Thanks!

Comment: Uhm, are you using the correct cli tool? It is `vendor/bin/doctrine-module` by default. It should work if your doctrine is set up correctly (i.e. if you can use it in your application). (I might have misunderstood your question.)

Comment: i'm using this one but I just dont understand how to use it. i create a fixture class... and then? the example says something about a `Loader()` which I use at some point... why? i thought I just need to put my class somewhere and register it? but how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fixtures are not available yet in the `DoctrineModule`. There is a distinct module for specifically fixture loading with Doctrine and it's called the `DoctrineDataFixtureModule` and can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/Hounddog/DoctrineDataFixtureModule).

Install it via composer: `hounddog/doctrine-data-fixture-module` and enable `DoctrineDataFixtureModule` in your application.config.php. If you configured doctrine already, just add this to your `FooModule`'s module.config.php:

```
'data-fixture' => array(
    'location' => __DIR__ . '/../fixtures',
)
```

And in that module's directory create a subdirectory called "fixtures". Put your classes there and run `vendor/bin/doctrine-module data-fixture:import` to import the fixtures. An example of a fixture class could look like [this](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures#doctrine-data-fixtures-extension)

Comment: thanks, great one! i added an example class for explanation when others try to follow your example

Comment: ok, my edit was rejected for some mysterious reason... maybe you could add it yourself? i think it would make your good post even better ;)

Comment: The edit was rejected because it changed too much the existing post (and the meaning of the post). I updated my answer to have a link to the Github repository of the data fixture module, so there are some examples how to write fixture classes.